# How to share instance of dexieDB with React app and service worker?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, dexie

I am trying to access data in service worker of the instance that was created in react app, but i am not able to find a way to share instance, i can use indexedDB native API to get data from indexedDB in service worker, but that is not desirable, is there any way to create DexieDB instance and share it across app and service worker?